# Find PHP.ini through automated script

Tags: php, apache, nginx, iis, php-ini

We have built special extension for PHP. It can be deployed on RHEL, Ubuntu & Windows OS including containers. We would like to give liberty to the user so that, s/he can enable the extension on need basis by executing simple scripts. We are exploring the possibilities to build the automated script to add extension entry into the respective php.ini.

There are many permutations to find the ini file, because PHP application can be hosted on various servers like apache, nginx & IIS. Addition to that, each website can point to different PHP version. Some sever has multiple modes, for example Apache has modes like prefork, php-fpm, etc. We can have multiple websites hosted on those servers with different settings and poiting to differnt PHP versions.

We need to find the appropriate php.ini to add the extension entry. How can we find the appropriate php.ini for the given website hosted on any server?

I know we can run `php -i` in command prompt. This will give php.ini location for PHP CLI. But, webserver may be pointing to different php.ini.

Other option could be to create simple info.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and access it into browser. But, it's manual process. I want to automate it using some script.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a bash script or a command to find any "php.ini" file on your server, you can use

```
find / -type f -name "php.ini"
```

or you can change "/" to a subfolder from which start searching.